# Hilt: Inherited fragment class not generated

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I've the following inheritance chain:

ZipCodeFragment:

```kotlin
class ZipCodeFragment : BaseUserOnboardingFragment(R.layout.user_onboarding_zip_code_fragment) { 
    // code
}
```

BaseUserOnboardingFragment:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseUserOnboardingFragment(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int = 0) : BaseFragment(layoutRes) { 
    // code
}
```

BaseFragment

```kotlin
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment, ErrorListener { 

    constructor() : super()
    constructor(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int) : super(layoutRes)
}
```

Following the steps described [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#why-use-the-plugin), I've annotated my `ZipCodeFragment` as follow:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint(BaseUserOnboardingFragment::class)
class ZipCodeFragment : Hilt_ZipCodeFragment(R.layout.user_onboarding_zip_code_fragment) { 
    // code
}
```

When compiling, I got the following error as if the Hilt class is not properly generated:

```
error: [Hilt]
public final class ZipCodeFragment {
             ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint class expected to extend Hilt_ZipCodeFragment. Found: Object
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the Hilt Gradle plugin?   That instruction is only applicable if you aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue: `abstract class BaseUserOnboardingFragment(@LayoutRes layoutRes: Int = 0)` has a default constructor parameter which is not supported yet.

Comment: This is still not supported, amazing, Dagger is supposed to help with dependencies and at the end depending on Dagger avoids you to do many things.